# I want to know the exact text height of each line, what method can be used to achieve it?

Tags: line, height, textheight

As shown in the figure below, I want to know the height from the bottom to the top of each line of text. Is there a way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: The height you seem to refer to includes ascenders and descenders, but a text line might have them or not. Do you need this for any specific line or in general the "maximum" value?

Comment: Hello, I want to perform this operation for all rows, and I want to get the maximum value including ascenders and descenders

Comment: The information you want is not in general available in pdftex or xetex you can get it in luatex see for example the lua-visual-debug package

Comment: Hello, can you be more specific? grateful

Comment: why do you want the height of the visual characters rather than \baselineskip which is the space allocated to each line, whichever characters appear on that line?

Comment: Because I want to distinguish each line accurately, I have tried \baselineskip before, but in this case, each line will contain a certain amount of white space.

Comment: you haven't said where or why you want this information, if you add `\showoutput` then the information is in the log file so you could extract it with suitable scripting, but to get it within tex look at the lua package I mentioned earlier